# VueJS Component: Code coverage for separate file with vue-class-component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, code-coverage, vue-class-components, mocha-webpack

I am trying to generate code coverage for VueJS components that are written in TypeScript using [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) decorators, and with separate `.ts` files for the actual logic of the component. E.g. for one VueJS component I have effectively two files, one `.vue` file with the HTML template that calls a `.ts` file containing the data / properties / methods into a class component.

For running tests I am using `vue-test-utils` along with `mocha-webpack` and code coverage is done using `istanbul/nyc`.

Here is my `package.json` tests-specific configuration:
[image: Extract from package.json]

And here the rules for coverage in my webpack configuration file:
[image: Extract from webpack.test.config.js]

Finally also one extract of a test for a VueJS ProgressBar component:
[image: Sample from VueJS test]

The tests on the component are running fine, however the `ProgressBar` component is not listed in my coverage.

The only workaround I found to get coverage for class components is to actually instantiate them  in the tests (e.g. `progressBar = new ProgressBarClass()`) however this defeats the purpose of vue-test-utils... Any ideas?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, simply updating ts-jest to a version >= 23.10 solved the coverage reports

Comment: This is not really an answer, you should have written this remark as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Diego - however this did not solve my issue (I am not using ts-jest)